# On click test to see what is clicked and run function accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an isotope gallery that has items that are small and enlarge upon click. I am doing this using this code:

```
$container.on( 'click', '.element', function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass('large');
    $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

This works but I have a button within the item or element and if I click the button the item will resize again which is not what I want. I then tried this code:

```
var buttonClicked = 'Button Clicked!';
$container.on( 'click', '.element', function() {
  if ( $( this ).is( ".button" ) ) {
    console.log(buttonClicked); //Do Nothing if Button is Clicked
  } else {
    $( this ).toggleClass('large');
    $container.isotope('reLayout');
  }
});
```

This doesn't work however. The item still resizes. From using `console.log` it doesn't appear to register that the button is being clicked.

I am unsure what I have wrong in my code or if I am not using `.is()` correctly.

*HTML*

There are two types of buttons within the elements. A button group and a solitary button.

Button Group Type HTML:

```
<li class="element" data-category="hybrid">
  <p class="type">H</p>
  <h2 class="name">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <p class="info">No Info Available</p>
  <ul class="button-group radius">
    <li><a class="button black view-button" href="#">View</a></li>
    <li><a class="button black review-form-lb" href="#review-form-lightbox">Review</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Solitary Button HTML:

```
<li class="element" data-category="hybrid">
  <p class="type">H</p>
  <h2 class="name">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <p class="info">No Info Available</p>
  <p class="review"><a class="button radius small black review-form-lb" href="#review-form-lightbox">Review</a></p>
</li>
```

How do I solve the problem to where if a button is clicked within the element the item will not toggle the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an anchor and your are trying to check for button, use hasClass property of jQuery to check the button class of anchor.

Use `event.target` to get the actual clicked element.

```
var buttonClicked = 'Button Clicked!';

$container.on('click','.element', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("button")) {
        console.log(buttonClicked); //Do Nothing if Button is Clicked
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('large');
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. The same thing happens.

Comment: That works but I had to modify the code: `$container.on( 'click', '.element', function(event) {//...` I had to add `event` to the function otherwise it would throw an error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Lynda in chrome it works fine, but for firefox yes you have to add, let me change add it in my answer.